# Angles Comparasion Loss Function for Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, angle, loss-function

I have a CNN, takes in an image, outs a single value - an angle. The data set is made of (x = image, y = angle) couples.

I want the network for each image, to predict an angle.

I have found this suggestion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/218547 But I can't seem to understand how to translate it into a working Tensorflow in Python code.

```
x_CNN = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 14, 14, 3))
y_CNN = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
keep_prob_CNN = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
one_hot_y_CNN = tf.one_hot(y_CNN, 1)
def MyCNN(x):
    # Network's architecture: In: Image, Out: Angle.
logits_CNN = MyCNN(x)

# Loss Function attempt <------------------------------
outs = tf.tanh(logits_CNN)
outc = tf.tanh(logits_CNN)
loss_operation_CNN = tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * (tf.square(tf.sin(one_hot_y_CNN) - outs) + tf.square(tf.cos(one_hot_y_CNN) - outc)))

learning_rate_placeholder_CNN = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
optimizer_CNN = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate_placeholder_CNN)
training_operation_CNN = optimizer_CNN.minimize(loss_operation_CNN)
correct_prediction_CNN = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits_CNN, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y_CNN, 1))
accuracy_operation_CNN = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction_CNN, tf.float32))

# And a working Training and testing code...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is going in the right direction, but the idea is that, instead of having `MyCNN` produce a single angle value for each example, produce two values. So if the return value of `MyCNN` is currently something with shape like `(None,)` or `(None, 1)`, you should change it to `(None, 2)` - that is, the last layer should have one more output. If you have doubts about how to do this please provide more details about the body of `MyCNN`.

Then you would just have:

```
outs = tf.tanh(logits_CNN[:, 0])
outc = tf.tanh(logits_CNN[:, 1])
out_radians = tf.atan2(outs, outc)  # This is the final angle output in radians
```

About the loss, I am not sure I understand your Y input. If you are trying to predict an angle, shouldn't it be a float value, and not an integer? In that case you would have:

```
# Example angle in radians
y_CNN = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,))

# ... 

loss_operation_CNN = tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * (tf.square(tf.sin(y_CNN) - outs) +
                                           tf.square(tf.cos(y_CNN) - outc)))
```

Comment: About the second code window in your comment, changed to float32, and also changed 0.5 * THINGS into tf.scalar_mul(0.5, THINGS) .
About the first code window, the link I gave says that using Atan2 isn't recommended, compared to the other method, of using Tanh. What do you think about that ?
outs = tanh(ylogit), outc = tanh(xlogit)) with a loss function 0.5((sin(pred) - outs)^2 + (cos(pred) - outc)^2

Comment: @MikoDiko As I understand it, what the linked post suggests is that trying to define the loss in terms of the result of `atan2` (using `out_radians`, in this case) is not a good idea, and instead it is better to use `outs` and `outc` to define the loss. This is what I am doing here, the loss is computed from the predicted sine and cosine. However, if you want to retrieve the actual angle value, you need at some point to go from sine and cosine to radians, and for that you need `atan2` - but again, this is not used in the training, only as output.

Comment: @MikoDiko I'm not sure there should be any difference between `*` and `tf.scalar_mul` in this case but I suppose it works just as well.